# Can't Open LXTerminal from PCMan 1.2.4

Tags: virtualbox, pcmanfm, lxterminal

Windows Machine using Oracle VirtualBox, Ubuntu.

I inadvertantly let my file system get full.  While working on this issue, at some point PCManFM lost its connection to open LXTerminal at the currect directory. (Where one right-clicks on a directory and the context menu includes "Open in Terminal".)

Since then I have removed files and emptied the trash so I now have 3% free space available on the drive.

But PCManFM still doesn't know how to launch LXTerminal.  At some point I entered "LXTerminal" into the Terminal location on preferences.  Well that turned out to be a bad idea.  Open In Terminal now tells me

```
Error: Failed to execute child process "LXTerminal" (No such file or directory)
```

and all I can do is hit the OK button.  It never takes me to any kind of Preferences window like it did before.

Can someone help me figure out how to get this working again?

Comment: Well, IIRC the default preferences entry for the terminal command is `x-terminal-emulator %s` - have you tried setting it back to that? or (lower case) `lxterminal %s`?

Comment: No, I haven't and can't. The state of the problem is that I can't open the window to set which terminal opens.  I click "Open in Terminal" and the error message only has an Okay button -- no option to edit the setting.  I select Properties on the File icon and there is no way to edit the terminal command setting.

Comment: I thought you were referring to the pcmanfm --> Edit --> Preferences --> Advanced dialog?

Comment: Steeldriver, you have solved my problem. If you want to elevate it (somehow) to an Answer, I will accept it.  Here is what happened: When the link to lxterminal broke, it would take me directly to Advanced Dialog, I just didn't understand that that was what it was.  After I entered the wrong name into the Terminal Emulator field, it would no longer take me directly there, and I didn't know where to find it.  So in your second statement, you told me how to find it again, which I did, then corrected the name of the emulator, and it works fine.